# Unit testing only controller file instead of express framework

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js

I am trying to unit test my controller file that handles a particular request. I do not want to test express as we have another mechanism for testing our Apis. I am stubbing the data using sinon. But the response is not what I am expecting.. I am always getting back a 200 status instead of the 201 that I am supposed to receive. Am I missing out on any specific part? I am using Typescript and mocha

my spec.ts file is

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
import {HiringCompanyJobHandler} from 
"../../source/Handlers/HiringCompanyJobHandler";
import * as httpMocks from 'node-mocks-http';
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import Jobs from "../../source/DAL/model/job";
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {Response, Request, Express} from 'express';


describe("Hiring Company Job Handler Unit Test Cases", () => {
let request = null;
let response = null;

beforeEach(function () {
    response = httpMocks.createResponse();
});

it("Should return the job details that belong to a particular company", (done) => {
    request = {
        query: {
            UserName: 'HiringCompany',
            CompanyID: '1'
        }
    };

    let expectedJobs = [
        {
            'hiringCompanyId': '1',
            'companyJobId': 'T1',
            'jobName': 'Plumber',
            'jobType': 'Permanent'
        }, {
            'hiringCompanyId': '1',
            'companyJobId': 'T2',
            'jobName': 'Electrician',
            'jobType': 'Temporary'
        }
    ];

    sinon.mock(Jobs)
        .expects('find')
        .resolves(expectedJobs);

    let hiringCompanyJobHandler = new HiringCompanyJobHandler();
    hiringCompanyJobHandler.GetBasicJobInformationForHiringCompany(request, response);

    expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(201);        
    done();

})
});
```

My controller code is as follows

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { isNullOrUndefined } from "util";
import JobDal from "../DAL/jobdal";


export class HiringCompanyJobHandler {
constructor() {

}

public GetBasicJobInformationForHiringCompany(req: Request, res: Response) {
    let userName = req.query.UserName;
    let companyID = req.query.CompanyID;
    let status = req.query.status;
    let jobDal = new JobDal();
    jobDal.GetHiringCompanyJobDetails(companyID,status).then((details) => {
        if (details.length > 0) {
            res.status(201).send({ details });
        }else {
            res.status(200).send({ status: "No jobs found!" });
        }
    }).catch((error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    });
}
```

}

```
export default new HiringCompanyJobHandler();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resolves` does not appear to be available for mocks (check the api [here](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.2/mocks/)).
I guess that you want to modify the behavior of the method `find` in `Job`, and that this method is called inside `GetHiringCompanyJobDetails`. Is that correct?

I think though that you should stub the method `GetHiringCompanyJobDetails` instead, so your test is pure unit test, since in here you are unit testing the method `GetBasicJobInformationForHiringCompany`. But this would be part of a different discussion.

In any case, **you should use a stub if you want to modify the behavior of a method** to meet the requirements of the path you want to test.
Check the sinon API for stubs [here](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.2/stubs/). I hope this solves your issue. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your observation. I should be stubbing GetHiringCompanyJobDetails. But I am not sure if the res.status will return a 201. I will check it out. Thanks

Comment: Oh it definitely should. If you stub `GetHiringCompanyJobDetails` and set its behavior to resolve with `expectedJobs`, then when running your test, the stubbed method will run instead of the actual method behavior.
Also, notice that `GetHiringCompanyJobDetails` is a method from `Job` class. You'll need to stub it with: `sinon.stub(Job.prototype, 'GetHiringCompanyJobDetails'...`, because then in your code you create jobDal, which is "an instance" of Job. Let me know if you have any issues :).

Comment: So I did stub my GetHiringCompanyJobDetails and am able to make the stub resolve my expected output. But the issue is that the status of 200 is returned instead of 201. On debugging a bit I found out is because the method GetBasicJobInformationForHiringCompany has res.status(201).send({details}) and the framework is unable to recognise it and return the control to the test. But if I do a promise.resolve and return the stubbed value, I am able to get the value in my test.   hcJobHandler.GetBasicJobInformationForHiringCompany(request, response).then(function(success){ i get the value here });